# php server and sql image upload

Tags: php, mysql, image

Ok,

I have built an insert image page (uploader.php) on the back of a previous post with regards to setting up a php image uploader, but am having a few issues......

The code is:

```
<?php 

$target = "images/test/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

$title=$_POST['title']; 
$desc=$_POST['desc'];  
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

mysql_connect("dbhost", "dbuser", "dbpass") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()) ;  
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('$title', '$desc', '$pic')") ; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?> 

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST"> 
Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br> 
Description: <input type="text" name = "desc"><br>  
Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Add"> 
</form>
```

So the first issue is that the information is not being entered into the database - the table has 4 fields - id(int), title(varchar), desc(varchar) and photo(varchar). Is it because the id field is not being specified?? This is simply the auto incremented primary key for the table.

The second issue is that the image that is being loaded contains spaces in it - for example, when uploading `"test image.jpg"` - I would like to incorporate a `str_replace()` to create `"testimage.jpg"`. Do you know where I would insert this into the code?

Thanks again for any help,

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't explicitly list columns in your insert statement, you must include all of them in the `VALUES ()`, so yes you would need to include the `id`

Better though, would be to list the columns:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (title, `desc`, photo) VALUES ('$title', '$desc', '$pic')") ;
```

Note that `desc` is backquoted above.  It is a MySQL reserved keyword and is a syntax error there unless quoted.

Also, please escape your values against SQL injection!

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']); 
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);  
$pic = (mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo']['name']));

// And your space replacement
$pic = str_replace(" ","", $pic);

// Now that it's cleaned up, you can insert.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (title, `desc`, photo) VALUES ('$title', '$desc', '$pic')") ;
```

Comment: hmm - I update the 4 lines as recommended and included the str_replace, BUT.....

the image is being uploaded (but without removing the spaces- still test image.jpg on the server), and one row is inserted in the database - but apart from the id - all field are blank....!? My code is exactly as above with the exception of these changes

Comment: Are you certain that your `$_POST` values are not empty?  do a `var_dump($_POST)` to make sure the values are in there to begin with, and also echo out your SQL statement string before sending it to `mysql_query()`

Comment: Ok have got it working now - dont know what I was doing - just started fresh using the above code and the image is placed correctly on the server and the details are correctly entered into the database table.
However, for some reason, 2 lines are inserted into the table - one blank and one with the details - do you have any idea why this could be happening - happy to send the full code through over the above thread if that helps. Thank!

Comment: started a new thread for this issue at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467886/duplicate-empty-line-entered-into-mysql-on-file-upload
hope you can help,
thanks

Comment: @JD2011 If you have 2 database entries for each upload,you must have two `mysql_query()` calls.  If my answer wasn't clear, it's not intended to use both of the `mysql_query()` calls above - only the one after the string escaping.